# getting rid of the certain columns in the loop

Tags: r

```
outliers <- d_car_nb %>% 
  group_by(factor, segment) %>% 
  mutate(hinge_spread = 1.5*IQR(sold_fee), 
         lwr = quantile(sold_fee, .25) - hinge_spread, 
         upr = quantile(sold_fee, .75) + hinge_spread) %>%
  filter(sold_fee > upr | sold_fee < lwr)

outliers_sold_fee<-outliers %>%
  select(quotedate,factor,segment,sold_fee)
print(outliers_sold_fee)
```

I am not sure how to loop across this function so that fill in different KPI each time other then sold_fee and each time a new dataframe is obtained with (quotedate,factor,segment,'kpi')

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The key to the solution is to call the `filter()` and the `select()` functions of `dplyr` in such a way that keywords referring to variables are evaluated using SE (**standard evaluation**, i.e. where variables are given as strings (e.g. `"sold_fee"`, as in `outliers[,"sold_fee"]` in base R)), as opposed to NSE (**non-standard evaluation**, where variables are given as unquoted text (e.g. `sold_fee` as in `outliers$sold_fee` in base R))(*).

**NSE is the default type of evaluation in functions defined in** `dplyr`, which makes referring to variables from a value stored in another variable (which is what you need in order to make the desired loop work as you want) not straightforward.

From the documentation for `filter()` and `select()` we deduce that the way to use SE in each of them differs, as follows:

In `filter()` we should use the `.data` pronoun. In your example, it would be:

```
v = "sold_fee"
filter(.data[[v]] > upr | .data[[v]] < lwr)
```

In `select()` we should use the `all_of()` functions. In your example it would be:

```
v = "sold_fee"
select(quotedate, factor, segment, all_of(v))
```

That said, you can now adapt your code so that the `sold_fee` name is read from an array containing your analysis variables and loop on them. You would then use the above usage forms for `filter()` and `select()` to obtain what you want.

In a final note, notice that you could store the result of the data frame containing the columns you want to visualize in terms of the outliers in a list and then print all at once after the loop has finished, as in:

```
library(dplyr)

vars4analysis = c("sold_fee")  # List all the variables you want to analyze for outliers here
outliers_info = list()
for (v in vars4analysis) {
  outliers = ...                         # filter command here
  outliers_info[[v]] = outliers %>% ...  # select command here
}
print(outliers_info)  # This will show the info about the outliers for each analysis variable
```

(*) You can read more about non-standard evaluation here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html